# Find All Span in a Text

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a text of 10000000 character in that I want to find all the **span** which have the **font-family:Symbol"**
my text may have many span without **font-family:Symbol"** but I just want to know only those span which have **font-family:Symbol"** and it's text on which it is apply.

any one please help me to find that span with text via any REGX.

Comment: Can you show the example of text and I'll help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this regex

```
string strRegex = @"(<span[\s\w\W]*?style='font-family:Symbol'[\s\w\W]*?>([\s\w\W])*?</span>)";

Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex);
```

Comment: How to find all spans in a collection?

Comment: use myRegex.Matches() method look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332118(v=vs.71).aspx